# Why does the following code always go inside the if block?

Tags: c#

Could anyone please tell me how I could resolve this issue ?

```
int a = 3;
if(a != 1 || a!=2 || a!=3 )
{
    //Comes in here ? Why ? When a=3 ?
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: If (a != 1 OR.... well, when a is 3, a is certainly not equal to 1. Since you used OR, it doesn't have to worry about the rest. You might be looking for AND. `if (a != 1 && ...`

Comment: Tip: If code doesn't do what you expect it is usually not because it didn't run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, and it's a common mistake. When speaking naturally, you'd say you want the `if`-block to execute when `a` is not 1, 2, or 3. Natural language however may lead to confusion and ambiguity and care must be taken when translating it into a formal boolean expression. In boolean logic, a correct expression would be:

```
if( !(a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3) ) { ... }
```

Using [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), we can rewrite this negation as:

```
if( a != 1 && a != 2 && a != 3 ) { ... }
```

Here, the atoms (`a == 1`, `a == 2` and `a == 3`) are negated and the disjunctions (`||`) become conjunctions (`&&`).

This may seem counter-intuitive at first but on closer inspection it's logical that this is indeed the correct expression.

Your original expression will evaluate to `true` if `a != 1`, or if `a != 2`, or if `a != 3`. Clearly, if one of those atoms fail (say, `a = 1` so `a != 1` returns `false`), another atom must succeed (`a != 2` and also `a != 3` when `a == 1`). The disjunction (`||`) evaluates to `true` if (at least) one of the atoms returns `true`. As we just showed, there is always at least one atom which is `true` and thus the whole disjunction  is always `true`. It's a [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29), not exactly what we were looking for.

The correct expression will evaluate to `true` if `a != 1` *and* `a != 2` *and* `a != 3`. The conjunction (`&&`) succeeds if *all* atoms succeed. For example, if `a == 1`, the first atom fails and thus the whole conjunction fails. This is what we want.

Answer (score 2):

Because `a != 1`.

When using the `||` (or) operator, the code will enter the `if` block when any of the conditions are `true`. Since, one of the conditions will always be `true`, it will always enter the if block.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking code to run if a is not 1, a is not 2 **or** a is not 3.

So that code will always run, because there is no value of a that can return false for all those conditions at once.

Answer (score 0):

its going in there becuase you are using `or` `||`

so on the first statement `a != 1` is true and it goes on in.

if you dont want it to do that then change `||` to `==` then it wont go in until all the statements are true.

Answer (score 0):

Because `a != 1` and `a != 2`.

```
int a = 3;
if(a != 1 && a!=2 && a!=3 )
{
    // Wont run
}
```